# GROUP BY multiple data types

Tags: sql, group-by, max, case, type-conversion

I have a table with two columns FieldName and FieldValue which are both varchar. The FieldName/FieldValue could be expiry dates or quantities like so:

[image]

I'd like to select all rows and group them by their max quantity and max expiry date preferably without splitting it out with a UNION.

I tried the following but received "Operand type clash: numeric is incompatible with date"

```
SELECT
    FieldName, 
    CASE FieldName
        WHEN 'Quantity'
            THEN MAX(CAST(FieldValue AS NUMERIC))
        WHEN 'Expiry'
            THEN MAX(CAST(FieldValue AS DATE))
    END AS FieldValue
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY FieldName;
```

Is it possible to mix data types like this?

Comment: A `case` expression's return data types must be compatible. (Numeric and date aren't.)

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as well formatted text.

Comment: `CAST` MAX value to VARCHAR - then the 2nd column will always be VARCHAR.

Comment: @i486 that would help a bit, though you still wouldn't be able to group by that column. That is why I suggested a nested query in tandem with a cast in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Better do this - you have only and exactly 2 values for grouping:

```
SELECT 'Quantity' AS Type, CAST(MAX(CAST(FieldValue  AS NUMERIC)) AS VARCHAR) AS MaxValue
  FROM MyTable WHERE FieldName='Quantity'
UNION 
  SELECT 'Expiry', CAST(MAX(CAST(FieldValue  AS DATE)) AS VARCHAR)
    FROM MyTable WHERE FieldName='Expiry'
```

Generally, it is bad idea to put different kind of values in the same column. You may have FieldName with current values (Qty/Exp) and 2 other columns one for Quantity and one for Expiry with possible empty (NULL) values.

Comment: Thanks i486. Yea, I had tested out UNION before and it worked out. I had hoped I could do it without  a UNION since the data in the table is actually more diverse than the example I used.

Answer (score 0):

No.
The column which you're labeling "FieldValue" must have a given data type. You're putting two different types into one!

If you need to have both of these values, consider the following:

```
SELECT
    FIELDNAME
    ,FIELDVALUE
FROM (
    SELECT
        FieldName, 
        CASE FieldName
            WHEN 'Quantity'
                THEN CAST(MAX(CAST(plm.CodeValue AS NUMERIC)) AS VARCHAR(50))
            WHEN 'Expiry'
                THEN CAST(MAX(CAST(plm.CodeValue AS DATE)) AS VARCHAR(50))
        END AS FieldValue
    FROM MyTable) A
GROUP BY FieldName;
```

Comment: Thanks Eli! Unfortunately, without a GROUP BY in the subquery I don't think we can perform a MAX on the FieldValue.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi, Try this -**

```
select FieldName,
CASE 
WHEN FieldName = 'Quantity' THEN   
  cast((select max(cast(FieldValue as numeric)) from #tmp where 
FieldName='Quantity') as varchar)
else
 cast((select max(cast(FieldValue as date)) from #tmp where 
 FieldName='Expiry') as varchar)
end  as 'New'
from MyTable
```